# Category names in cart page magento

Tags: php, magento

I am using Magento 1.7 and I wanted to display category name in the cart page,from which products are added to the cart ..

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
echo Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getProduct()->getCategoryIds($_item->getProductId()))->getName();
```

add this line near product name or where you want category name in `app/design/frontend/default/[yourtheme]/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`

hope this help you

Comment: its working i checked it ok please tell me the error occur when you implement it

Comment: its is throwing error SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Where exactly i have to place that code...bcoz i have placed it near product name and its throwing me a error.

Comment: i have added in the same place..but still the same error..do i need to change core files?

Comment: no core file should be never edited. please cross check the file and path which is the above one that i specify

Comment: `getCategoryIds` might return multiple ids `load` expects one.

Comment: Crossed checked it...everything is fine...but don know y it is throwing error @magExp

Comment: The problem is due to blank array passed in execute function that\’s why through the exception. or product assign to more than one category